Issue with ChakraUI component: Page becomes unresponsive after use
Recently, in a project, I wanted to use ChakraUI with React. I installed it as the documentation suggests for Vite and wrapped the main.jsx with ChakraProvider. I'm using the drawer component, but after using it on the page - by opening and then closing it - the page becomes unresponsive and I can't click anywhere on the page. This is resolved only if I do Ctrl + S in Visual Studio Code or if I reload the page. Below is the component, and I'm available for any further assistance. No errors in console.
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { TicketContext } from "../context/TicketContext";
import { FaShoppingCart } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Drawer, DrawerOverlay, DrawerContent, DrawerCloseButton, DrawerHeader, DrawerBody, Button, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
const Navbar = () => {
  const { cantidadTickets, setCantidadTickets, handleCompra } =
    useContext(TicketContext);
  const [isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
  const [ticketResumen, setTicketResumen] = useState("");
  const [totalCompra, setTotalCompra] = useState(0);
  const drawerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOutsideClick = (event) => {
      if (drawerRef.current && !drawerRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setIsDrawerOpen(false);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleOutsideClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleOutsideClick);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Generar el resumen y calcular el total de la compra
    if (cantidadTickets > 0) {
      const total = cantidadTickets * 5000; // Costo de cada ticket en pesos chilenos
      setTotalCompra(total);
      setTicketResumen(`Estás comprando ${cantidadTickets} ticket(s)`);
    } else {
      setTotalCompra(0);
      setTicketResumen(""); // Limpiar el resumen si no hay tickets
    }
  }, [cantidadTickets]);

  const sumarTicket = () => {
    handleCompra(1);
  };

  const restarTicket = () => {
    if (cantidadTickets > 0) {
      handleCompra(-1);
    }
  };

  const onClose = () => setIsDrawerOpen(false);
  const onOpen = () => setIsDrawerOpen(true);

  return (
    <div className="navbar-container">
      <nav className="navbar">
        <ul className="nav-list">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink
              className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "active" : undefined)}
              to="/"
            >
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink
              className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "active" : undefined)}
              to="/compra"
            >
              Compra tu número
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink
              className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "active" : undefined)}
              to="/premios"
            >
              Premios
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Button
              className="cart-icon"
              onClick={onOpen}
              leftIcon={<FaShoppingCart />}
              variant="outline"
            >
              {cantidadTickets !== undefined && cantidadTickets > 0 && (
                <span>({cantidadTickets})</span>
              )}
            </Button>
            <Drawer
              isOpen={isDrawerOpen}
              placement="right"
              onClose={onClose}
              finalFocusRef={drawerRef}
            >
              <DrawerOverlay />
              <DrawerContent>
                <DrawerCloseButton />
                <DrawerHeader>Carrito de compras</DrawerHeader>
                <DrawerBody>
                  <div className="ticket-container">
                    <Button className="btn-pink" onClick={sumarTicket}>
                      +
                    </Button>
                    <Text>{cantidadTickets}</Text>
                    <Button className="btn-pink" onClick={restarTicket}>
                      -
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                  {cantidadTickets > 0 && (
                    <>
                      <Text>{ticketResumen}</Text>
                      <Text>Total: ${totalCompra}</Text>
                    </>
                  )}
                  <NavLink
                    to="/compra"
                    className="btn-pink"
                    style={{ width: "100%", marginTop: "20px" }}
                  >
                    Ir a Comprar
                  </NavLink>
                </DrawerBody>
              </DrawerContent>
            </Drawer>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink
              className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "active" : undefined)}
              to="/galeria"
            >
              Galería
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink
              className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "active" : undefined)}
              to="/terminos"
            >
              Términos y condiciones
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;


I want to utilize the component without experiencing any further page freezes.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
